# Vim, how to search by current word under cursor?

Tags: vim

For example

```
  test test word
```

Currently the cursor is under `word`, and I want to search by `word`, normally I would do select `word` and copy it. then type `:/` and paste and return.

Is there any shortcut for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+search+word+under+cursor

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `*` to search forward and `#` to search backward, for the word under the cursor. Once you initiate the search, you can use `n` to repeat it in the same direction or `N` in the reverse direction. Or else use `*` or `#` again from the word that you landed on.

The `*` and `#` commands basically initiate searches as if you used `/\<word\>` or `?\<word\>`. Thus these searches can be recalled with up arrow at the `/` or `?` search prompt.

Comment: And for any (also contained) occurrence of the `word` (as asked), there are the `g*` and `g#` variants.

Comment: I was about to start coding a vi-macro!